# retrieve captcha and login using curl php

Tags: php, session, curl, web, captcha

I am working on a project.So i have to get the captcha code from the site mentioned below.The user will submit the captcha and his login credentials and then i have to extract the data(for user's benefits). But after i submit the captcha,simply the login page appears and nothing happens.

i have tried this with multiple sites and simply the login page appears. I know how to fetch data after logging in,but the captcha is really giving a headache

```
<?php

 $cookie="cookie.txt";
function open($url)
{

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.2) Gecko/20070219 Firefox/2.0.0.2');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);  
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}

function between($string, $start, $end)
{
    $out    = explode($start, $string);

    if(isset($out[1]))
    {
        $string = explode($end, $out[1]);
        echo $string[0];
        return $string[0];
    }

    return '';
}

function get_captcha()
{
    $url    = 'https://academics.vit.ac.in/student/stud_login.asp';

    $open   = open($url);

    $code   = between($open, '<img src='https://academics.vit.ac.in/student/captcha.asp', '">');

   // echo 'https://academics.vit.ac.in/student/captcha.asp' . $code;

    return 'https://academics.vit.ac.in/student/captcha.asp' . $code;
   //return ;

}


function rahul()
{
    $capth=htmlspecialchars($_POST['code']);

    echo $capth;

    $username="xyz"; 
$password="abc"; 
$url="https://academics.vit.ac.in/student/stud_login.asp"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt";
$veri=$capth;

$com="Login";

$postdata = "regno=".$username."&passwd=".$password."&vrfcd=".$veri."&submit=".$com;

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);  // <-- add this line
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

echo $result;  


$data = curl_exec($ch);

}




?>


 <html>
 <body>
<form action="" method="post">
<img src="<?php echo get_captcha(); ?>" border="0" /><br />
<input type="text" name="code" value="<?= isset($_POST['code']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['code']) : '' ?>" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<?php


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 rahul();
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case, open capcthca image directly from CURL and return with binary code.

```
<?php
$cookie='cookie.txt';
if(!file_exists($cookie)){
        $fh = fopen($cookie, "w");
        fwrite($fh, "");
        fclose($fh);
}
$ch = curl_init();   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://academics.vit.ac.in/student/captcha.asp");  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE,1);         
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookie);      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);   
curl_close($ch);  
$ImageCaptcha=base64_encode($result);
?>
```

View the image base64 encode

```
<?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$ImageCaptcha.'">'; ?>
```

i've been tested this code & it's work for me